# IBM VisualAge RPG pasword change gives error Cannot locate the JRE in registry, Need JRE

Tags: java, websphere, rpg, visual-age

We have a legacy IBM VisualAge RPG application which handles the user signon process to the IBM AS/400 (iSeries, IBMi). If the user's password has expired the program prompts for a new password. When it comes to change the password on the AS/400 it calls FVDCWVC9.DLL entry point VARPG_Change_Password. This is explained in the IBM manual *Programming with VisualAge RPG Version 6.0 for Windows® SC09-2449-07*.

However, in Windows 10 it just shows an error message:

**Cannot locate the JRE in registry. Need JRE.**

From the (VARPG) code it looks like it is returning error code 312 which causes the app to display *'Password will be disabled with next invalid attempt'*.

My Windows 10 does have a JRE installed but it is the AdoptOpenJDK JRE 8u275-b01 (x64).

Assuming my analysis is correct, does anyone know exactly what FVDCWVC9.DLL is looking for when it is looking in the registry for a JRE? Perhaps a Sun/Oracle Javasoft JRE?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: I've experienced different behavior of IBM java based products (not VARPG) and AdoptOpenJDK whether AOJ version was Hotspot or the other one. If I remember well it talked about java and registry. AOJ Hotspot works. Does it help ?

Comment: @nfgl Later I did try a couple of Oracle JREs

Comment: If I look inside the DLL I can see the error message. Near it is what seems to be a path of  vjre/bin/classic. This is where I have the run-time and it is the same on both my Win 7 and Win 10 with just Win 10 not working. Maybe the current directory is set differently for Win 10 though I cannot find a way of telling what that is for the running app.

Comment: Did you try some 32 bits JRE ?

Comment: @nfgl I had tried with jre-6u31-windows-i586-s.exe which I presume is 32-bit, but it didn't solve the problem. I will try setting the JAVA_HOME env variable today. Thanks.